# Is it possible for a uniform discrete distribution (uniform_int_distribution) to generate sequential (or the same) numbers when used correctly?

Tags: c++, c++11, math, random, uniform-distribution

Going to put my edit up here:

In the comments, the actual nature of randomness has been discussed. What I do understand is that no number is more or less likely than another to be generated when generating "random" numbers.

Hopefully a fairer re-phrase of my question is:

If no number is more or less likely than another, then, why can a uniform distribution function call itself that if the numbers aren't always going to be uniformly distributed?

---

Just to be clear before I ask, I am only asking out of curiosity. Lucky for me I am not a cat.

I have created a quick sort function for a University project, and thought that maybe (rather than just bashing away at the keyboard for a while) I could test it with some lists of integers generated randomly.

```
std::vector<int> unsorted_list;
std::random_device ran_dev; // Initialise a new random device
std::uniform_int_distribution<> uni_dist(1, 100); // Create Uniform Distribution
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    unsorted_list.push_back(uni_dist(ran_dev));
}
```

Can I fully rely on this implementation to produce random numbers that do always appear to actually be random (evenly distributed)?

You might think I'm being silly... Clearly the class states that it is a uniform distribution, as in, it's not possible to be non-uniform... But are any of these outputs even *possible*? And if so, how likely?

```
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
```

I suppose the last output is more likely than the first or second (especially when using bounds of 0 to 100), but my curiosity still has me.
Am I being particularly foolish? I've never been *very* good at maths, so, although I'm beginning to understand symbols and terminology, I still look at some explanations and simply "glaze over", so my googling so far hasn't been helpful.

Comment: Yes, all of those outputs are possible and no, the likely hood isn't different between 1 and 3

Comment: Sure a random number generator can produce those results. A 100-sided die can come up with 5 1s in a row, or any other sequence. Just because it doesn't *look* random to us doesn't mean it *isn't.* The probability that the generator produces a '2' isn't dependent on what it previously produced--the outputs are meant to (be a good approximation of) independent of one another.

Comment: Yeah, I figured these kinds of answers might be the case. Isn't it true though, that when rolling a dice, the chances of rolling the same number 100 times is less likely than rolling mostly different numbers every time? Or is that complete hogwash? I mean, this is supposed to be a uniform distribution, when wouldn't it be uniformly distributed?... Am I misunderstanding what uniform distribution means?...

Comment: (using the 100-sided die) It is, but they're apples and oranges. The probability of rolling a *specific sequence* is 100^n, where *n* is the number of elements in the sequence. That's the case regardless of how random the numbers in a sequence look: 1,2,3,4,5 is as likely as 55, 32, 41, 97, 10. The probability of rolling a different number from what you just did is 99/100, but the probability of rolling *any specific* number is 1/100.

Comment: So, if the sequence is a hundred 1s in a row, when generating numbers between 1 and 2,000,000,  the 101st number is no more likely to be different to 1 even though the last 100 have been a 1?...
That kinda sucks to think about. There I was thinking I'd been beating roulette all this time, but actually I just got lucky.  
Ohhh, your last edit made a bit more sense. The chance of a different number is 99/100 but the chance of rolling a specific number is 1/100... Does that not affect the likelihood of my list having different numbers rather than all the same? At all?

Comment: For rolling the same number each time in an n-trial set, you've got a likelihood of 100 * 1/100^n: for 1, 1, 1..., the likelihood is 1/100^n. But then you've got 2, 2, 2... and 3, 3, 3... etc. There are 100 possible sequences like that, so multiply the 1/100^n probability by 100 to get the probability of all the elements being the same.

Comment: @Matthew exactly right!

Comment: Injecting a bit of humour: https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: Try it with a die with a smaller number of faces, like 6 or even 2 (a coin)--over enough trials, you'll be able to see that the likelihood of any number isn't influenced by the previous number.

Comment: I think what I mean is, although I completely accept that, that's how "random" works... When generating using uniform_int_distribution I can put a mapping together of how often a certain number is generated and it's in line with the rest. There are no numbers that peak or trough significantly. This is the bit I am questioning. Or is the answer still the same even though it appears (over 100,000 generations) that the distribution really is even?

Comment: @Matthew sort of, and also sort of not. As detailed, the probability of any specific sequence happening is 1/100^n, and there are only 100 specific sequences that are just the same number repeated over and over, compared with the orders of magnitude more numbers of sequences where that isn't the case. So it's very unlikely, *but* no more unlikely than any other specific sequence. It's just you can recognize the sequence better than most others, and it doesn't look 'random' to you--because humans are good at finding patterns even where there aren't any.

Comment: Well then why does it get to call itself a uniform distribution? If it isn't always uniform... (Hopefully narrowing down to the question I had intended to ask).

Comment: Why would you call a die a uniform number generator if it rolls three 1s in a row? Because even if it may occasionally do that, it's still within the realm of appropriate behavior for a uniform number generator. Short enough sequences will *appear* to have some order some of the time, but that's an illusion.

Comment: So, why is a uniform number generator different from a non-uniform random number generator if that is true?
OHHHH hold on, does it just mean that the likelyhood of each number appearing is uniform? Unlike, for example, rolling a pear and it standing on one *end* it's more likely to fall on a side? Unlike a dice where each side is (more or less) just as likely as another?

Comment: @Matthew because as the trials go to infinity, the distribution of results becomes uniform

Comment: Maybe think of it the opposite way? If rolling a '6' made a '6' less likely for the next trial, it would make the number generator *more* predictable, not less--you'd be right more often if you guessed '7' than if you guessed '6' as the next result. With fully independent, uniformly distributed results, you wouldn't be better off choosing any number over any other--each would have a probability of 1/100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are much more likely to get a list with lots of different numbers than a list with lots of repeats. However, a true RNG will produce any number of 1s in a row if used long enough, and inasmuch as a PRNG is supposed to look like a true RNG, a PRNG might be expected to do the same.

True RNGs typically have independent trials, meaning the outcome of one trial does not tell you anything about the outcome of the other. Knowing one hundred 1s have come up in a row tells you nothing about what such a RNG will do on the next trial. Inasmuch as PRNGs are meant to look like RNGs, you might expect the same from them.

In summary, it is possible, though unlikely, to get a lot of repeats. If you want no repeats, I would recommend picking elements yourself and then shuffling. That way the order is random whereas the elements have whatever distribution you want, exactly.